# Turning a Django project into a cloud SaaS project

Tags: django, python-3.x, nginx, uwsgi

I have a Django 2.2 project. I am installing this project to several companies. But for every company i create a server install mysql, django, uwsgi, nginx... So all belongs to that company.

I want to serve this django project system as a cloud service. So every company will be member. When they get member and pay, they will start to use their system on cloud. But companies will be isolated from each other.

I am not sure how to do that. Should i write whole project again ? Or should i automize all installation prosesses with scripts and when they register and pay, scripts will make installations and will start to serv its project on nginx. Should i use different databases for every project... Lots of questions and couldn't figure out right design.